# Responsive view like Whatsapp web using Boostrap 4 and Ember

Tags: html, css, ember.js, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to implement Whatsapp web like UI.
I'm using Bootstrap 4 and Ember 3.2.
The base idea is working now. I've done the message box which is on the bottom of the view (using **fixed-bottom** Bootstrap class). I've messages list which is automatically scrolling down using jQuery inside list container custom component like:

```
export default Component.extend({
    didRender() {
        this.$().parents('html, body').scrollTop(this.$(document).height()); // Scroll immediately
    }
});
```

Here I have the margin set for list:

```
    <div id="ember390" class="ember-view">
    <div class="container-fluid pt-5" style="border: 1px solid red;margin-bottom: 32vh;">
            <div class="d-flex flex-column">
                <div class="p-2">
                    1
                </div>
                <div class="p-2">
.......
```

I'm adding **margin-bottom: 32hv** which is "lifts up" the message list on the message input box. This solution works on full HD screens.
Once I'm trying the same view on small displays the **margin-bottom: 32hv** is not enough because of Bootstrap responsive.

I've got one solution, but not sure is it correct.
I can calculate the **margin-bottom** value by window size and message box container.

Is it only one way, or can I do the same with pure CSS?

Another issue is to use jQuery with Ember.js, so I can't get access to message input container inside the message list container component.

Here is example https://www.bootply.com/QKVffslOIf

Comment: I'm not familiar with whatsapp -- is it chat? 
I work on https://emberclear.io, which is a chat that uses flexbox classes to achieve a fixed-to-bottom chat entry. is that similar behavior?

Instead of using margin-bottom: some number, I just used flexbox. Lemme see if I can summarize an example.

Answer (score 2):

So, if you're doing a chat app with chat at the bottom like what I'm doing with https://emberclear.io, I think flexbox might be better suited for you.

basically, this *can* be done with pure css! :)

here is what I do:

chat/template.hbs

```
<div class='flex-grow flex-column align-items-stretch chat-container'>

  {{outlet}}

</div>
```

chat/privately-with/template.hbs:

```
<ChatHistory class='flex-grow flex-column' @messages={{messages}}/>

<ChatEntry class='p-l-md p-r-md' @to={{model.targetIdentity}} />
```

I've been carrying this around with me on multiple projects, but this is the gist of what is happening -- not sure if bootstrap has similar classes or not (i'm using bulma sass functions and variables):

```
@mixin flexUtils($modifier) {
  .flex-row#{$modifier} {
    display: flex !important;
    flex-direction: row;
  }

  .flex-column#{$modifier} {
    display: flex !important;
    flex-direction: column;
  }

  .flex-wrap#{$modifier} { flex-wrap: wrap; }
  .flex-grow#{$modifier} { flex-grow: 1; }
  .flex#{$modifier} { display: flex; }

  @for $i from 0 through 20 {
    .flex-width-#{$i * 5}#{$modifier} {
      flex-basis: #{$i * 5%};
    }
  }


  .align-items-start#{$modifier} { align-items: flex-start; }
  .align-items-end#{$modifier} { align-items: flex-end; }
  .align-items-center#{$modifier} { align-items: center; }
  .align-items-stretch#{$modifier} { align-items: stretch; }
  .align-items-baseline#{$modifier} { align-items: baseline; }
  .justify-content-start#{$modifier} { justify-content: flex-start; }
  .justify-content-end#{$modifier} { justify-content: flex-end; }
  .justify-content-center#{$modifier} { justify-content: center; }
  .justify-content-space-between#{$modifier} { justify-content: space-between; }
  .justify-content-space-around#{$modifier} { justify-content: space-around; }
  .justify-content-space-evenly#{$modifier} { justify-content: space-evenly; }
}



@include mobile {
  @include flexUtils('-mobile');
}

@include tablet {
  @include flexUtils('-tablet');
}

@include desktop {
  @include flexUtils('-desktop');
}

@include flexUtils('');
```

Comment: You have done really good work! The chat app looks awesome! Unfortunately it works differently, that I need to done.The *ChatEntry* is sticky to the *ChatHistory* . Once I have filled up the *ChatHistory* the *ChatEntry* is hides on scrolling. My task is to have the *ChatEntry* on the same position. However I'l try utilize the flexbox

Comment: you want your chat entry to always be visible? or to hide on scrolling?
(I think mine stays on the screen, even when chat history is huge)

Comment: yes I want to keep the *ChatEntry * always at the bottom of screen.

Comment: that's what mine does :)

Comment: I guess I found _quick'n'dirty_ solution. I've just added 4 `<div class="p-5">` elements after list. The Bootstrap is "calculating" responsive values same way to all elements, thus p-5 class adding the same margin. It is not best solution still :(